# How can i calculate the center of the map from KML data?

Tags: openlayers, kml, center

So, i use openlayers, with several base map layers (google, bing, osm), and i have a KML layer, with placemarks everywhere. What is the best way to calculate the center of the map, and the optimal zoom level?

Thank you!

the kml snippet:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>foo</name>
    <description>
       foobar
    </description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>lat,lon</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: If your KML layer is all over the globe, then the center of the map is... well, at the hot molten centre of the earth? :) Assuming a small area, can't you get the bounding box from OpenLayers and just zoom to that?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the extent containing all data from your KML layer:

```
map.zoomToExtent(KMLLayer.getDataExtent());
```

see: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getDataExtent